# why value variable is not changed?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, timer, boolean

I have a `Timer` in my winForms and when the `TimeSpan` is `0` I set `done` as `true` and try check the value a thread.

My code:

Initial variables:

```
private DateTime endTime = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(1);
private bool done;
private bool running = true;
private int count = 0;
private delegate void setLabelMethod(string msg);
private void setLabelValue(string msg) { label2.Text = msg; }
```

Timer handling:

```
private void timer1_Tick_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TimeSpan remainingTime = endTime - DateTime.UtcNow;

            if (remainingTime <= TimeSpan.Zero)
            {
                label1.Text = "Done!";
                timer1.Enabled = false;
                done = true;
                running = false;
            }
            else
            {
               //...
            }

        }
```

Thread callback function:

```
private void test()
        {
            do
            {
                if (done)
                {
                    Invoke(new setLabelMethod(setLabelValue), "yeah");
                    done = false;
                }

                Thread.Sleep(500); 

            } while (running);
        }
```

Start `timer1_Tick` and `Thread` executions.

```
 private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Thread th = new Thread(new ThreadStart(test));
            th.Start();
            timer1.Enabled = true;
        }
```

the problem is that the following statement in `.test()` method not ever is `true`,why?

**statement**

```
 if (done)
 {
    Invoke(new setLabelMethod(setLabelValue), "yeah");
    done = false;
 }
```

Someone can point my mistake? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The *done* variable must be marked volatile to work properly in the Release build.  You possibly didn't wait long enough.  Add a millisecond instead of a minute.

Comment: Why do you use multi-threading in the first place? Your code doesn't look CPU bound to me. There is rarely a reason to use this kind of multi-threading if you're not limited by the computation power of a single core.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Martin James mentioned, instead of **polling flags**, you should be using 
**thread synchronization** mechanisms.

This simple example shows how you can do this using `Monitor.Wait`, `Monitor.Pulse` and `lock`.

The important difference between this and your code is that this will **stop the thread from running** until the condition has been met, thus **improving** the **performance** of your code.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ThreadExample example = new ThreadExample();
        Thread thread = new Thread(example.Run);

        Console.WriteLine("Main: Starting thread...");
        thread.Start();

        Console.WriteLine("Press a key to send a pulse");
        Console.ReadKey();

        lock (example) //locks the object we are using for synchronization
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Sending pulse...");
            Monitor.Pulse(example); //Sends a pulse to the thread
            Console.WriteLine("Pulse sent.");
        }
        thread.Join();

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

class ThreadExample
{
    public void Run()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Thread: Thread has started");
        lock (this) //locks the object we are using for synchronization
        {
            Monitor.Wait(this); //Waits for one pulse - thread stops running until a pulse has been sent
            Console.WriteLine("Thread: Condition has been met");
        }
    }
}
```

To modify your code to use this mechanism, you need to maintain the reference to the object you used to start the thread (in this example, I will call it `threadObject`)

```
private void timer1_Tick_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TimeSpan remainingTime = endTime - DateTime.UtcNow;

        if (remainingTime <= TimeSpan.Zero)
        {
            label1.Text = "Done!";
            timer1.Enabled = false;
            lock(threadObject){
                Monitor.Pulse(threadObject); //You signal the thread, indicating that the condition has been met
            }
        }
        else
        {
           //...
        }
    }
```

Then, in your `test()` method, you only need this:

```
private void test()
    {
        lock(this)
        {
            Monitor.Wait(this); //Will stop the thread until a pulse has been recieved.
            Invoke(new setLabelMethod(setLabelValue), "yeah");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You have no [synchronization](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/threads/thread_synchronization.aspx) protecting the 'done' variable. When an object or variable may be accessed in one thread while another thread is, or might be, modifying it, some form of synchronization is needed.

The ways it can actually fail are many. For example, consider this loop:

```
private void test()
    {
        do
        {
            if (done)
            {
                Invoke(new setLabelMethod(setLabelValue), "yeah");
                done = false;
            }

            Thread.Sleep(500); 

        } while (running);
    }
```

Suppose the compiler knows that `Thread.Sleep` does not modify `done` or `running`. It may conclude that nothing in this loop modifies `done` or `running` (assuming `done` is false when the loop is entered) and therefore it can cache `done` (and `running`!) in registers across calls to `Thread.Sleep`.

In other words, it can 'optimize' your loop to:

```
private void test()
    {
       if (done)
           Invoke(new setLabelMethod(setLabelValue), "yeah");
       done = false;
       if (running)
          while(1) Thread.Sleep(500); 
    }
```

Notice that this is a bona fide optimization, if `done` and `running` don't have their values changed by other threads. The compiler is free to assume this since it violates the rules to modify a value in one thread while another thread is or might be accessing it without synchronization, this thread might be accessing those variables, and this code contains no synchronization functions.

Of course, your code doesn't have to worry about this if you follow the rules. The compiler is prohibited from making 'optimizations' that break your code and you don't have to worry about how it does it. But that only applies if you follow the rule. (In practice, the compiler will not cache a value in a register across a call to a synchronization function and volatile variables will never be cached in registers.)

Comment: A sync should not be necessary for a boolean.  The reads and writes should be atomic.

Comment: Your second part of the code is going to test for done only once, then run only the Thread.Sleep(500); - I don't think this is intended.

Comment: Atomicity isn't the problem. Concurrency is. The test for 'done' need only be done once. Once 'done' is set to false, the compiler is free to assume nothing else can change it. (Since it's not volatile and the code doesn't invoke any synchronization functions.)

Comment: However, your additional comments written after I released the lock on the first comment seem like they may be on the mark.  We need synchronization around edits in posts and associated comments!  +1

Answer (score 0):

In your `timer1_Tick` method, you have set `running = false;` - and your thread is depending on this variable to loop. As far as I can see, this is used to stop the thread once the condition has been met.

You could do this by moving this statement to your thread:

```
private void test()
    {
        do
        {
            if (done)
            {
                Invoke(new setLabelMethod(setLabelValue), "yeah");
                done = false;
                running = false;
            }

            Thread.Sleep(500); 

        } while (running);
    }
```

This way you ensure that the thread code will be run when the condition is met. What may have been happening is that the thread had already past the `if (done)` statement when your `timer1_Tick` code sets the `running = false;` thus stopping the thread. Remove the `running = false;` statement from your `timer1_Tick` method.

Comment: That should 'work' too. The OP code whould have to be very, very lucky to ever get past the 'running' flag check and find the 'done' flag set - it would have to preempt the timer handler between the 'done' set and the 'running' clear and it only tries to do that every half second.  I suppose that, if left for a few years and the timer and thread intervals were assumed to have no synchronism, it would eventually happen.  In the case where there is little drift between the timer and sleep, it might take millenia.

Comment: ..because, though your fix works, polling flags is a poor design, so you have raised 'not working' to 'working badly' :)  Still, it's better than my suggestion of a sleep(1000) to allow the thread to spot the 'done' flag, which merely raised 'not working' to 'totally sucks but just about runs' :)

Comment: I agree, polling flags sucks :) I'm gonna write another solution although it seems OP lost interest as he is not replying

Comment: @Nico - OP has probably been seduced by the dark side of inter-thread comms - sleep/yield loops, 'done' flags :(

Answer (score 0):

Your thread spends 99.9999% of its time sleeping, then it tests the 'running' flag, exits if it is false and then tests the 'done' flag, then sleeps again.  The timer handler sets the 'done' flag and then clears the 'running' flag.  The chances are overwhelming that, when the timer eventually fires, the thread will find the 'running' flag cleared and so exit before it ever gets to checking the 'done' flag.  Try putting  a sleep(1000) between setting the 'done' flag and clearing the 'running' flag.  Then try a better signaling mechanism than polling flags!